# Can't connect MongoDb via JNDI in java

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to connect MongoDB through JNDI in wildfly using the below code.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
MongoClient mongoClient = (MongoClient) ctx.lookup("java:global/MyMongoClient");
```

But i am getting the following error.

```
 Exception->com.mongodb.MongoClient cannot be cast to com.mongodb.MongoClient
```

I am using mongo-java-driver-3.4.0.jar in "wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/mongodb/main" directory and "mongodb-driver-3.4.0.jar" in "wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/APPLICATION.war/WEB-INF/lib". Why am i getting the above exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will get ClassCastExceptions when the class is loaded with one classloader, then try to cast it to the same class loaded by a different classloader.

The classes are represented by two different Class objects inside the JVM and the cast will fail.

Since Mongo-driver is supplied by WildFly, try *not* bundling it with your application (WAR) - if using Maven, mark the driver as *provided*.

Comment: Thanks for giving the clues. I solved it by using jboss-deployment-structure.xml to load Mongo-driver supplied by wildfly. My another question is, Is there any way to get the connected database name from MongoClient object.